# R Error importing when import JSON file using the fromJSON function

Tags: r

I'm trying to import a JSON file using the `jsonlite` library.

When I run the `fromJSON` function, I get the following error -

```
df <- fromJSON("Inputfile.json",flatten = TRUE)


Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       ÿþ[                     (right here) ------^
```

Any suggestions for a workaround? Thanks

`sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 4.0.1 RC (2020-05-30 r78643) 
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) 
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363) 

Matrix products: default 

locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252 LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252 LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C LC_TIME=French_France.1252
```

Comment: Your error is slightly formatted somewhat unreadable. I am assuming the arrow points to the characters at the same line? Either way the problem is that it does not know how to read a specific Character. This might be a problem in your locale setting, or it might be a similar problem that Asian characters had from 4.0.0 to 4.0.4 (fixed in 4.0.5). Could you share more information such as your `sessionInfo()` and format your error accordingly?

Comment: R version 4.0.1 RC (2020-05-30 r78643)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_France.1252

Comment: It's strange that I'm getting this error because I've got another JSON that is structured exactly the same way as this file. And it imports fine.

Comment: Potentially a line ends in a null string `\0`. (Can happen unexpectedly). If that's the case reading the file as text `txt <- scan(file)` and removing those before reading it in as json `fromJSON(gsub('\\0', '', txt))` might fix it. I'm not the most experienced in this specific problem, so it might not work, but surely someone will pop in with a suggestion if this is the case.

Comment: I think I got it. It was a UTF-16 encoded file. I saved as UTF-8 and re-ran the function. It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saved the file from UTF-16 to UTF-8 and the function worked.